# A certain measure on Banach algebras

Tags: real-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, measure-theory, ergodic-theory, banach-algebras

**According to the  comments  of Nate Eldredge  I did revise the question. In particular I change "$C^{*}$ algebras" to  "Banach  algebras".**

Is there a reference who introduce the following measure on Banach  algebras and investigate it from the view point of  Banach  algebras  or from the view point of ergodic theory?:

Let $A$ be a Banach   algebra. We define an outer measure $ m^{*}$ on $A$ as follows:
For $B \subset A$ we put $$m^{*}(B)=\mu  ^{*} \left(\bigcup_{b\in B} \mathrm{sp}(b)\right)$$
where $\mu^{*}$ is the standard outer measure of $\mathbb{C} \simeq \mathbb{R}^2$. Then the Caratheodory methods gives us a measure space structure on $A$ with measure $m$.
This measure is an invariant measure for both scalar translation and inner automorphism of algebras.

Does this construction gives us nothing new when $A$ is the matrix algebra?
In particular is it true to say that, for the matrix algebra, a subset is measurable in this spectral sense if and only if it is mea
surable in the classical sense?

**As the final question: Is there  a  Banach  algebra $A$ for which this  measure  construction does  not  lead to triviality: that is  $A\neq \mathbb{C}$ would  have  subsets with  positive  finite  measure?**

Comment: It definitely doesn't make the Borel sets measurable.  As you suggest, let $X$ be two points, so $A = \mathbb{C}^2$ and the spectrum of $(z,w)$ is $\{z,w\}$.  Let $C \subset \mathbb{C}$ be your favorite Borel set of finite positive measure, let $v \notin C$, and consider the sets $B_1 = \{(u,v) : u \in C\}$, $B_2 = \{(v,u) : u \in C\}$.  Then $B_1, B_2$ are certainly Borel, and $B_1 \cap B_2 = \emptyset$.  But we have $\bigcup_{b \in B_1} \operatorname{sp}(b) = C \cup \{v\}$ and the same for $B_2$, as well as $B_1 \cup B_2$. [...]

Comment: So $m^*(B_1) = m^*(B_2) = m^*(B_1 \cup B_2) = \mu(C)$ and thus $m^*$ is not countably additive on these sets, so they are not measurable.

Comment: @NateEldredge  Thank you for  your  very interesting  comments. What  about  the  unit  Ball in $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$?Is it easy to  compute the integral of trace on this  ball, if it is measurable?

Comment: @NateEldredge   According to your very helpful comment I realize that the  unit  ball is  not measurable  since $\begin{matrix} \lambda&k\\0&\lambda \end{matrix}$ is  disjoint from the unit  ball where $\lambda$  varies in the unit  disc  and $k$  is  a  very  large  constant. Your  comment perhaps  shows that we  do  not  get interesting measure theory  on C*  algebras  because of exsistence of  nilpotent  elements in non commutative  case, so I revise the question with replacing C*  algebras  by  Banach  algebras.Thanks  again for your  comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is just a fishing expedition; it does not seem that sufficient thought was put into the question beforehand

Comment: @YemonChoi  It is just a suggestion to define a measure on a Banach algebra. Is this definition a duplicate definition?any way  it is not a fishing expedition.